# Change every NSArray within NSDictionary to Mutable

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am having problem with the following code, I need to do some modification on each array within a NSMutableDictionary. When I first added those array into the dictionary, they are "MutableArray", but when I try to do something with them, they become a "NSArray".

here is my code:

```
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"cell: %@", cellText);

    Boolean flag = false;
    NSMutableDictionary *myTempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.tableContents copyItems:YES];

    for (NSString *key in myTempDict) 
    {
        NSLog(@"1st for");
        for(NSString *myString in [myTempDict objectForKey:key])
        {
            NSLog(@"2nd for");
            if([myString isEqualToString:cellText])
            {
                if([[myTempDict objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]])
                {
                    NSLog(@"mutable");
                }
                else if([[myTempDict objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
                {
                    NSLog(@"not mutable");
                }
                [[myTempDict objectForKey:key] removeObject:myString];
                break;
                NSLog(@"break1");
            }
            NSLog(@"2nd for end");
        }
        if(flag)
        {
            break;
            NSLog(@"break2");
        }
    }
    self.tableContents = myTempDict;
    [tableView reloadData];
```

now when I run it, it generate the following error:

- cell: 12-01244476
- 1st for
- 2nd for
- not mutable
- -[__NSArrayI removeObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c02580
- Current language:  auto; currently objective-c

on my viewdidLoad I created those Array to be NSMutableArray, but now its back to NSArray, why?
and any idea on how to tackle this problem?

really need help on this.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you making a copy of the dictionary, rather than operating on the original dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acording to the documentation of [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/initWithDictionary%3acopyItems%3a)

The copyWithZone: method performs a shallow copy. If you have a collection of arbitrary depth, **passing YES for the flag parameter will perform an immutable copy of the first level below the surface**. If you pass NO the mutability of the first level is unaffected. In either case, the mutability of all deeper levels is unaffected.

Why don't you try:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myTempDict = [self.tableContents mutableCopy];
```

Comment: WOW!!! Nice man! It took me like 7 hours yesterday to try to figure this thing out. you got it in seconds.